# Type error when running Apps Script to iterate array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is, most probably, something trivial, however I cannot figure out where the issue is.
My code below iterates through an spreadsheet (array). The colum 15 contains "true" and "false" values. For values true, the code sets string "This value is TRUE" to the column 18 in the same row.
Now, the code works fine, it does what it should, however after running, it says:

**TypeError: Cannot read property "15" from undefined.**

which refers to

```
if (array [i][15] == true)
```

The code is:

```
function arrayFun() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = app.getSheetByName("Activity");
  var array = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, 90, 16).getValues();       

  for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i ++) {
    if (array [i][15] == true) {
    activeSheet.getRange(i + 2, 18).setValue("This value is TRUE")
    } 
  }
};
```

Ah, values in column 15 are set by the tick box feature in google sheets.
Apprecaite any help on this.
Thank you

Comment: `<=`  Review JS array bounds

Comment: @tehhowch ````array = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, 90, 16)```` - checked that.

Comment: The issue isn't in the size of `array`, which are 90 elements by 16 elements per your `getRange` call. The error says that you cannot access element 16 (which is at index 15) of `undefined`. This means that whatever you are calling `[15]` on has the exact value `undefined`. So the issue isn't `[15]`--it's before that: `array[i]`.  Voted to close as typo.

Comment: @tehhowch found it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, thanks to @tehhowch:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
```